# A not understood input given to a local server

Tags: python, html, flask

I constantly get a 400 bad request Error on my localhost whenever my input is sent to the server. My app.py seems perfectly fine & also my html file. My model file works alright.

I tried looking into the code for any bugs but didn't find any & I also tried adding an if and else statement after

```
if input_variables in flask.request.form:
        prediction = model.predict(input_variables)[0]
        return flask.render_template('main2.html',
                                     original_input={'Temperature':temperature,
                                                     'year':year,},
                                     result=prediction,
                                     )
    else:
        prediction = "No movies selected. Please, select something!"
        return flask.render_template('main2.html',
                                     original_input={'Temperature':temperature,
                                                     'year':year,},
                                     result=prediction,
                                     )
```

,and it goes as this:

```
if input_variables in flask.request.form:
        prediction = model.predict(input_variables)[0]
        return flask.render_template('main2.html',
                                     original_input={'Temperature':temperature,
                                                     'year':year,},
                                     result=prediction,
                                     )
    else:
        prediction = "No movies selected. Please, select something!"
        return flask.render_template('main2.html',
                                     original_input={'Temperature':temperature,
                                                     'year':year,},
                                     result=prediction,
                                     )
```

I was expecting that I would send input to a localhost server that would give me the output from a Linear Regression Model my app.py file contains

```
import flask
import pickle
import pandas as pd
# Use pickle to load in the pre-trained model.
with open(fr'C://Users//khale//Code//web development//Other web lang//Python//test-model-app//walmart_model_linear.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
app = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates2')
@app.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if flask.request.method == 'GET':
        return(flask.render_template('main2.html'))
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        temperature = flask.request.form['Temperature']
        year = flask.request.form['year']
        input_variables = pd.DataFrame([[temperature, year]],
                                       columns=['Temperature', 'year'],
                                       dtype=float)
        prediction = model.predict(input_variables)[0]
        return flask.render_template('main2.html',
                                     original_input={'Temperature':temperature,
                                                     'year':year,},
                                     result=prediction,
                                     )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

my main2.html file contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    form {
      margin: auto;
      width: 35%;
    }
    .result {
      margin: auto;
      width: 35%;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
  </style>
  <head>
    <title>The Walmart weekly sales Model</title>
    <img
      src="https://www.supermarketnews.com/sites/supermarketnews.com/files/styles/article_featured_retina/public/Walmart_Canada_supercenter_exterior.png?itok=lVSg6uOM"
      ,
      width="308"
      ,height="160"
    />
  </head>
  <form action="{{ url_for('main') }}" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Input values:</legend>
      Temperature:
      <input name="temperature" type="number" required />
      <br />
      <br />
      Year:
      <input name="year" type="number" required />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <br />
  <div class="result" align="center">
    {% if result %} {% for variable, value in original_input.items() %}
    <b>{{ variable }}</b> : {{ value }} {% endfor %}
    <br />
    <br />
    Predicted Weekly Sales:
    <p style="font-size: 50px">{{ result }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</html>
```

my main.py contains

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\khale\\Code\\web development\\Other web lang\\Python\\walmart_model\\Walmart.csv')

data['Date'] = data['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
dt = data['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
data['year'] = [i.year for i in data['Date']]
data['month'] = [i.month_name()[0:3] for i in data['Date']]
data['day'] = [i.day_name()[0:3] for i in data['Date']]


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

figure, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(14,4), sharey=True)
bp1 = sns.barplot(data=data, x='day', y='Fuel_Price', hue='year', ax=ax1)
bp2 = sns.barplot(data=data, x='month', y='Weekly_Sales', hue='year', ax=ax2)
pp = sns.pairplot(data=data,
    y_vars=['Fuel_Price','Weekly_Sales'],
    x_vars=['year', 'Temperature'],
    kind='reg',
    height=4)

# pp_2 = sns.pairplot(data=data,
#     y_vars=['Fuel_Price','Weekly_Sales'],
#     x_vars=['month', 'Temperature'],
#     kind='reg',
#     height=4)

# pp_3 = sns.pairplot(data=data,
#     y_vars=['Fuel_Price','Weekly_Sales'],
#     x_vars=['day', 'Temperature'],
#     kind='reg',
#     height=4)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x = data[['year','Temperature']]
y = data['Weekly_Sales']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2,train_size=.8, random_state=1)

classifier = LinearRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, explained_variance_score, mean_absolute_error

predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
print(f'R^2 score: {r2_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=predictions):.2f}')
print(f'MAE score: {mean_absolute_error(y_true=y_test, y_pred=predictions):.2f}')
print(f'EVS score: {explained_variance_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=predictions):.2f}')
rp = sns.regplot(x=y_test, y=predictions)

import pickle
with open('walmart_model_linear.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(classifier, file)
```